# WS2811 RGB LED Strip Timing Issue

Tags: avr, assembly, led-strip

I recently purchased addressable RGB LED strips based on the WS2811 chip. These strips have a single data + clock line that uses NRZ style encoding to distinguish between a 1 and 0. The datasheet for the strip can be found at https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf

Since the timing is strict for these strips, I am trying to use assembly code to drive the strip (my first attempt with assembly).

Using Atmega168 @ 16Mhz (1 clock = 62.5ns), I call the following assembly code (which I expect to set the LED color to WHITE).

```
asm_pin_toggle:
sbi DDRC, 4

;reset the led strip data line ~50us
ldi R19, 255
loop:
    nop
    dec R19
    brne loop

ldi R19, 23 ;loop 24 times - all 1 bits
loop_all_1:
    sbi PORTC,4
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    cbi PORTC, 4

    dec R19
    brne loop_all_1


ret
```

However when I run this I get the color GREEN. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

There are many version of the WS2811 timing floating on the internet. The one I have used is

- T0H - 250ns
- T0L - 1000ns
- T1H - 1000ns
- T1L - 250ns
- RET - >= 50us

any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use the normal C delay macros?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No particular reason except I wanted to use this opportunity to learn bit of assemble as well.

Answer (score 2):

Problem fixed.

I was loading 23 into R19 register(hence the loop was only getting executed 23 times instead of 24).

Fixing that to 24 solved the issue.

Comment: further reading:
http://wp.josh.com/2014/05/13/ws2812-neopixels-are-not-so-finicky-once-you-get-to-know-them/